# Python regular expression: problem using findall to extract only integers from brackets

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to teach myself regex in Python and I'm experimenting with it. I found exercises to practice regex and I'm now facing some difficulties.

The exercise is to find and return the integers within brackets from a string. The function should return those values within brackets as well. There can be whitespace between the number and the brackets, but no other character besides those that make up the integer (- or + is allowed before the number, and - should stay in the returned list).

I have almost solved this, but I can't seem to find a solution to a small error.

My code returns `[47, -43, 12]`. It should return `[47, 12]`.

Therefore my regex statement should ignore numbers that have both + and - in front of them, but I can't get it to work. Thus, it should include negative numbers, but not numbers that have more than one + or - in front of them.

Here is my code.

```
import re
def integers_in_brackets(sample):
    t = re.findall(r"\[\s*\+?(-?\d+)\s*\]", sample)
    t = list(map(int, t))
    return t

def main():
    print(integers_in_brackets("afd [128+] [47 ] [a34]  [ +-43 ]tt [+12]xxx!"))
    #this test below works
    #print(integers_in_brackets("  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Try: `r"\[\s*[-+]?(\d+)\s*\]"`.

Comment: Group the signs: `r"\[\s*[+-]*(\d+)\s*\]"`

Comment: It has been asked already. Where do you get these tasks from?

Comment: @coderfrombiz, apart from the regex issue, I'd suggest to use `finditer` (and `map` or comprehension) instead of `findall+list+map`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/wmcyoI